# Input field not updating from redux state but displays value on console.log in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

> I am doing a todo list task using mern stack using redux as state
> management. I want to update my checkbox from redux state for
> completed task. Checkbox is always set to empty on page start
> eventhough some tasks are present as already completed in redux state
> i.e. checkbox set to true in redux state.

My code is as follow-

```
const TaskItem = ({tasks:{task,_id,date,checkbox},deleteTodo,loading}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        setformData({

            checkbox1:checkbox})
        
    }, [])
    console.log(checkbox);
const [formData,setformData]=useState({
    checkbox1:""
})

const {checkbox1}=formData;
const onChange=e=>{
    setformData({...formData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}

    return (
        <div className="list">
        <p>
        
        <Moment style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(27,112,137)", border:"1px"}}
        format='YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm a'>
        
        {date}
        
        
        </Moment>
        <br/>
        <input
            name="checkbox1"
            type="checkbox"
            value={checkbox1}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)}
            />
```

> [image: it is my screenshot of homepage and redux state]

Comment: There is no redux in the code you provided. Is the problem that the checkbox is not displaying right or that the state is not updating as you expect?

Comment: Is this tasks a single task or list of task `{tasks:{task,_id,date,checkbox}`?

Comment: See my redux state. I just edited my question. Indeed it's a list of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove this line

```
useEffect(() => {
        setformData({

            checkbox1:checkbox})
        
    }, [])
```

because it is calling setFormData again even though it's been changed in onChange function.

Comment: So, how can I make the checkbox already checked for value set to true in redux state without using useeffect? I have my checkbox form in my home page. So, whenever I start my server, checkbox should be checked for true values and not checked for false value.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you are trying to spread array in a wrong way:

Try to replace this:

```
tasks: {task,_id,date,checkbox}
```

with

```
tasks: [{ task, _id, date, checkbox }, { task: task2, _id: _id2, date: date2, checkbox: checkbox1 }]
```